# Copying shared_ptr passed to base class

Tags: c++, inheritance, smart-pointers

So I have a small hierarchy of classes and I need to pass down a `shared_ptr` to the base class that accepts a *rvalue*. However, in one of the cases I'd like to grab the `shared_ptr` for use in one of the *derived* classes.

My problem reduces to this:

https://godbolt.org/z/Kvaa7o1Gn

```cpp
class Base {
  public:
    Base(std::shared_ptr<int>&& p)
        : a_{p}
    {
    }

  private:
    std::shared_ptr<int> a_;
};

class Derived : public Base {
  public:
    Derived(std::shared_ptr<int> p)
        : Base(copy_shared_ptr(p)) // this is of course not permitted, but I'd like to do something like this
    {
    }

  private:
    std::shared_ptr<int> copy_shared_ptr(std::shared_ptr<int> p)
    {
        p_ = p; // segfaults
        std::cout << "Now p_ is " << p_.use_count() << std::endl;
        return p_;
    }

    std::shared_ptr<int> p_;
};

int main() { Derived d{std::make_shared<int>(5)}; }
```

It is not possible to grab the `shared_ptr` before moving it on, since I need to construct my *base* class before I can initialize it.
IS there anyway obvious idiom for achieving this that I might have missed?

Comment: For a **shared_ptr**, never do `std::shared_ptr<int>&& p` as a parameter.  Just do `std::shared_ptr<int> p` when extending federated ownership.

Comment: @Eljay why not? Moving should be marginally more efficient than copying as it'll avoid an increment and decrement of the reference count

Comment: the base subobject is constructed first. When you do `p_ = p;` then `p_` is not yet initialized

Comment: @463035818_is_not_an_ai, I know about the issue with the initialization order. Just wondered if there were anything I could do about it.

Comment: @Eljay, Yes, that is possible. But it is also about the semantics. I really want to show that this class takes ownership of the shared_ptr (it is not supposed to be shared outside this class).

Comment: yes sorry, my confusion, I didnt understand the question at first

Comment: @AlanBirtles • since it's a sink parameter, have the move on the inside:  `Derived(std::shared_ptr<int> p) : Base{std::move(p)} { }`

Comment: @SupAI • if it is **taking sole ownership**, have the parameter be a `std::unique_ptr`, not a `std::shared_ptr`.

Comment: @Eljay, good point. Then I'll convert it to a shared_ptr within the class.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can pass a copy to `Base` then store the original in `p_`

```
Derived(std::shared_ptr<int> p)
        : Base({p}), p_(std::move(p))
    {
    }
```

Comment: Smart! I first tried just passing a copy directly (which of course didn't work), but didn't think that I could just call the copy constructor to get a new rvalue.
This is exactly the answer I was looking for.